# замена jQuery на родной Javascript при работе с классами CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6, queryselector

Изучаю вопрос перехода от jQuery к родному Javascript.
Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что особенность jQuery в последовательном применении функций к одному объекту в JS пока нет, т.е.

из кода jQuery

```
$('#content')
    .removeClass('edit-error')
    .removeClass('edit-complete')
    .toggleClass('edit-error', this.m_pageData.is_wrong_text)
    .toggleClass('edit-complete', this.m_pageData.is_completed_text);
```

к коду Javascript

```
document.querySelector('#content').classList
    .remove('edit-error')
    .remove('edit-complete')
    .toggle('edit-error', this.m_pageData.is_wrong_text)
    .toggle('edit-complete', this.m_pageData.is_completed_text);
```

не перейти :(

да и `toggle` как-то не так работает

Comment: _"в JS пока нет"_ - jQuery - это библиотека, написанная на JS, так что всё реализуемо и только на JS. Но так как далеко не все "стандартные" методы возвращают `this`, то придётся обходиться без chaining-a. Или писать свои велосипеды-обёртки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку методы .classList не возвращают объект classList или объект DOM, вы не можете связать с ними цепочку.

Вы можете создать цепочки с помощью небольшого объекта с цепными методами:

```js
function classList (el) {
  const list = el.classList

  return {
    toggle (c) { 
      list.toggle(c) 
      return this 
    },
    add (c) { 
      list.add(c) 
      return this 
    },
    remove (c) { 
      list.remove(c) 
      return this 
    }
  }
}

const el = document.querySelector('#content')

classList(el).remove('foo').add('bar').toggle('baz')

console.log(el.className)
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Методы `remove, toggle, add` не возвращают ссылку на `Element.classList` поэтому их нельзя вызывать с помощью чейнинга(chaining).

jQuery это обертка над стандартными методами и после вызова он возвращает ссылку на тот же экземпляр `$('#content')`